# How to update Booktype?

Tags: python, django, booktype

How to update [Booktype](https://github.com/sourcefabric/Booktype/)? 
I installed it by linux command `apt-get install booktype` about six months ago and there are no updates from `apt.sourcefabric.org`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can install GCC/clang and the headers (if needed), then go to the GitHub repo you've linked your question to and then download the contents as a `.zip` file. Then unarchive it and run `python setup.py install` in the folder where the extracted contents were put. You can do `python setup.py --help` to get help.

Comment: Where i should unarchive .zip file ? (in folder of booktype progect or it irrelevant like temp folder)

Comment: @hitakiri, it doesn't matter. You can create a directory in the temp folder (just to be sure the files won't conflict) and unzip the files there.